# How a video can fill width of a page to 100% with a fixed height using HTML?

Tags: video, width, fixed

How a video can fill width of a page to 100%  with a fixed height using HTML? I do not want to see black bars.

Comment: Do you have any code at all to share?

Comment: No.. Only with javascript.....

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?